# Recreated png image is black

Tags: php, image-processing, gd

[image: example image]

Note : SO has converted the above reference image to jpeg. Here is the [transparent PNG](http://pngimg.com/upload/grass_PNG4930.png).

---

Following is an example code which recreates a png image **on a new canvas** and preserves the transparency. As you can see, it also allows pixel level manipulation eg. with a custom function like `custom_func($r, $g, $b)`, which is illustrated better at the bottom of this question.

Basically this code **recreates/redraws** the above image **on a new canvas** successfully as it is. *Please note, that sky is completely transparent in the above image*.

```
    $image = imagecreatefrompng('grass.png');

    $x_dimension = imagesx($image);
    $y_dimension = imagesy($image);
    $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($x_dimension, $y_dimension);

    // create a transparent canvas
   $trans_color = imagecolorallocatealpha($new_image, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 127);
   imagefill($new_image, 0, 0, $trans_color);

     for ($x = 0; $x < $x_dimension; $x++) {
          for ($y = 0; $y < $y_dimension; $y++) {
          $rgb = imagecolorat($image, $x, $y);
          $r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
          $g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
          $b = $rgb & 0xFF;
          $alpha = ($rgb & 0x7F000000) >> 24;
          //$pixel = custom_function($r, $g, $b);
          imagesetpixel($new_image, $x, $y, imagecolorallocatealpha($image, $r, $g, $b, $alpha));
      }
      }
     imagesavealpha($new_image, true);
     imagepng($new_image, 'grass-result.png');
```

---

However when I run the same code on this particular png image below.

[image: problematic png image]

It gives me an almost black image like this.

[image: very dark blue - almost black recreated image]

---

I would like to understand what is happening here and why ? Most importantly, I would like to know about possible factors that could influence the process, so I could look into it. Why is it that the result differs from one png to another ?

Ideally, I would like my code to be able to preserve and transfer the transparency state ( transparent, semi-transparent or opaque ) of the source png image, as it is, to the recreated image. As you can see, I have been able to achieve it, except for the case above.

---

Just in case, here is my environment. Windows 7 - 64 bit ** Wampserver2.5 ** Apache-2.4.9 ** Mysql-5.6.17 ** php5.5.12-64b. Also here is a var_dump of the image with `getimagesize()` :

```
array (size=6)
  0 => int 228
  1 => int 230
  2 => int 3
  3 => string 'width="228" height="230"' (length=24)
  'bits' => int 8
  'mime' => string 'image/png' (length=9)
```

---

**UPDATE**
Here is the proof that the example image is indeed transparent and also that it can be manipulated, while keeping the transparency. Notice the bottom of the image is more brownish now. This was achieved by a slight modification of this line `imagesetpixel($new_image, $x, $y, imagecolorallocatealpha($image, 100, $g, $b, $alpha));`

[image: manipulated transparent image]

Comment: "Please note, that sky is completely transparent in the above image."  No, it isn't.  Try looking at it on a non-white background.

Comment: And it's a JPG.  Your code expects PNG.  Have you uploaded the correct file?

Comment: Did not know SO converts pngs to .jpegs. Anyways, I will update the post now with proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second image is 8-bit, meaning it only supports a maximum of 256 colours.  This makes it a 'palette-based' image and as such it doesn't support alpha transparency.

By simply adding the following line after creating `$image` you can fix the problem:

```
imagepalettetotruecolor($image);
```

This doesn't have any impact on images that are already true colour, so `grass.png` continues to be processed correctly.  From the [PHP manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepalettetotruecolor.php):

> Returns TRUE if the conversion was complete, or if the source image already is a true color image, otherwise FALSE is returned.

Comment: Definitely works, any idea why the 32kb image becomes 119kb on recreation. ?

Comment: Because it's saved as a 32-bit image, instead of its original 8-bit format. You would need to reverse the operation with [`imagetruecolortopalette`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagetruecolortopalette.php) to reduce the file size again.